# Is there a ES6 shortcut for using member functions as event listeners?

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6, dom-events

This is not a duplicate of [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Some of the answers may be similar, [the **Question** is different](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292329/does-the-same-answer-imply-that-the-questions-should-be-closed-as-duplicate). You can see from the comments below the answers there are many solutions that are different because this is about ES6 not old JavaScript. This question is also about event listeners, not callbacks. A such there are other solutions that don't apply to plain callbacks.

---

If I have a class and I want to have some event call a function in that class I end up having to writing a bunch of boilerplate

```
class SomeClass {
  constructor(msg, elem) {
    this.msg = msg;
    elem.addEventListerer('click', (...args) => {  // Can these 
      this._onClickListener(...args);              // three lines
    });                                            // be simpler?
  }
  _onClickListener() {
     console.log(this.msg);
  }
}
```

Is there some ES6 syntactic sugar for using class methods as listeners? Ideally I'd like be able to do something like

```
class SomeClass {
  constructor(msg, elem) {
    this.msg = msg;
    elem.addEventListener('click', this._onClickListener);
  }
  _onClickListener() {
     console.log(this.msg);
  }
}
```

And have it correctly set `this` **and pass all arguments regardless of the event.**

But that doesn't work. Without the boilerplate `this` is not set.

```js
class SomeClass {
  constructor(msg, elem) {
    this.msg = msg;
    elem.addEventListener('click', this._onClickListener);
  }
  _onClickListener() {
    console.log(this.msg);  // this is wrong
  }
}

var s = new SomeClass("hello", document.querySelector("button"));
```

```html
<button>click me</button>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with anything in ES6, but you may do something with ESW (ECMAScript Whatever) decorators.

Comment: Generally you'd want `this` in the callback for an event listener to be the element, as at least some of the time it could be useful to actually access that element?

Comment: EventListener Interface provides a nice way to handle this: https://jsfiddle.net/ysLd6L35/

Comment: @squint: you should post that in an answer. It's pretty interesting. I had no idea there was a magic *call the handleEvent* on the object function

Comment: @adeneo, I can see how `this` as the element might be useful but for DOM events the element is also in `event.target`. Also I'm not looking for a solution for just DOM events. The code I'm writing is actually handing stuff in node.js but I wanted to post working code so I used a DOM event in the example

Comment: @gman: While `event.target` will get you the deepest element clicked, that's not necessarily the same as the element to which the handler was bound, which is what `this` would point to. However, the `event` object does have a `.currentTarget` property that is the bound element.

Comment: *"You can see from the comments below the answers there are many solutions that are different because this is about ES6 not old JavaScript."* None of the comments suggests an ES6 specific solution. I don't know if you read the answer in the duplicate, but it talks about ES6 as well, and the "method as event listener" use case is part of the question (`transport.on('data', this.alert);`). However, if @squint wants to add their solution as an answer, they can reopen the question and do so.

Comment: You can see below `(...a)=>this._onClickListener(...a)` an ES6 solution. It also seems like you'd notice this question is about event listeners not callbacks. As such there are other solutions like squint's `handleEvent` solution below that don't apply to callbacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to bind the context:

```
class SomeClass {
  constructor(msg, elem) {
    this.msg = msg;
    this._onClickListener = this._onClickListener.bind(this);
    elem.addEventListener('click', this._onClickListener);
  }
  _onClickListener() {
     console.log(this.msg);
  }
}
```

Additional advantage of this solution is that you can remove listener `elem.removeEventListener(this._onClickListener)`

Comment: Ugh! Brain fart. No idea why I forgot about `bind`. Interesting that you add a local bound method. I guess the advantage is you can later more easily remove the listener since you have a reference to the bound function.

Comment: @gman: No need to use `.bind()` if you're using ES6 syntax anyway. Just do `elem.addEventListener("click", event=>this._onClickListener())` Arrow functions don't have a `this` defined, so they get it from their outer lexical environment.

Comment: @squint: If I understand your example it's not going to pass arbitrary arguments is it? Whereas `bind` will.

Comment: @gman: In both cases it will pass the `event` object as the first argument.

Comment: I wasn't looking for a solution that passes just the `event` object. I was looking for a solution that passes all argument period regardless of the event. See the original code

Comment: @gman: Oh... `(...a)=>this._onClickListener(...a)` You were misusing `.apply()`

Answer (score 2):

```js
class SomeClass {
  constructor(msg, elem) {
    this.msg = msg;
    elem.addEventListener('click', this._onClickListener.bind(this));
  }
  _onClickListener() {
    console.log(this.msg);
  }
}

var s = new SomeClass("hello", document.querySelector("button"));
```

```html
<button>click me</button>
```

I might not be totally understanding you, but it works with `bind`.

Basically, `bind` *creates a copy* of the bound function with `this` always set to the specified reference. (You can also bind arguments, but that's irrelevant in this case.)

Comment: Yea, I had used `bind` before. No idea why I forgot :P   Doh!